How can I rename an existing file without moving it?
I have a directory where a Filewatcher waits for new files.
As soon as a csv file is printed, the watcher grabs it and business logic happens.
It appears that the FileWatcher grabs the file to early when java is still writing to the file. Therefore I get an error because the FileWatcher thinks the file is incomplete.
I would like to save the data to a .tmp file and then rename the file with java WITHOUT the necessity of moving it since moving often requires copying the file.
Is there a way of doing this?

File.renameTo?

What OS is this? At least on Unixoids, "moving often requires copying the file" requires a big asterisk.

I don't know of any modern (or ancient) OS or filesystem where moving a file within the same partition would involve copying the data. And if it does, it's for a reason and you can't just skip it.

Therefore I get an error because the FileWatcher thinks the file is incomplete. That's mysterious. What does it mean?

Looks a bit like an XY problem. The issue you're trying to touch files that are still being written to, you should find a way to avoid that not work around it. The tmpfile thing will work only as long as your files are never written to or deleted again after creation.

Files.move(from, to, StandardCopyOptions.ATOMIC_MOVE).
More generally, Files.move does what it says: It moves. However, it might implement this as 'copy it, then delete the from'. It tries not to.
With the ATOMIC_MOVE flag enabled, and the job can't be done without copy-then-delete, then you simply get an exception.
So, this doesn't so much change anything, it merely assuages your unfounded fear: If the thing you fear happens (it won't, unless you're doing something silly, like creating it on one file system and then 'moving' it to a location on another system, which, of course, cannot be done without copy-then-delete mechanics, for obvious reasons) - then you will get an exception.
